# Bisection method. Optimise function in C code

Tags: c, optimization, bisection

I have a comment from my teacher related to my code for bisection method. He said "The number of calculations of the function is not optimised. In fact, on each iteration, the function is calculated three times, although it would be enough once."

Could you please help me to optimise the calculations. I actually don't even see at which point the function is calculated 3 times.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<time.h>

double f(double x); //Function
int res(int i, double a, double b, double ξ, double ε1, double ε2); //Print result
double Bisection(double a, double b, double ε1, double ε2); //Bisection method

int main()
{
    double a=-10, b=0, ξ, h=0.5, α, x1, x2, ε1, ε2;
    int i=0;

    printf("\nf(x) = 2^x - 2 * cos(x)");
    printf("\nStart of the interval a = %.0lf", a);
    printf("\nEnd of the interval b = %.0lf", b);
    printf("\nEnter error ε1 for function = ");
    scanf("%lf", &ε1);
    printf("Enter error ε2 for argument = ");
    scanf("%lf", &ε2);
    printf("\n\nSOLUTION:");

    //selection of roots
    x1=a;
    x2=x1+h;
    while (x2<=b)
    {
        if ((f(x1)*f(x2))<0) 
        {
            i++;
            printf("\n\n%d) %d root of the function is in the interval [%.1f, %.1f]\n",i, i, x1, x2);
            printf("\nn\t     a\t\t   b\t\t ξ\t     f(ξ)\t     ε1\t\t    ε2\n");
            Bisection(x1,x2,ε1,ε2); //Bisection method
        }
        x1=x2;
        x2=x1+h;
    }
    return 0;
}

//Function
double f(double x) 
{
   double y;
   y=pow(2,x)-2*cos(x);
   return y;
}

//Print result
int res(int i, double a, double b, double ξ, double ε1, double ε2) 
{
   printf("%d\t%10.7f    %10.7f    %10.7f    %10.7f    %e    %e\n", i, a, b, ξ, f(ξ), ε1, ε2);
   return 0;
}

//Bisection method
double Bisection(double a, double b, double ε1, double ε2)
{
    double ξ=(a+b)/2; //Middle of the interval
    double α;
    int i=0;
    if (f(ξ)==0) 
    {
        printf("Root: %f \n\n", ξ);
    }
    else 
    {
        while ((fabs(f(ξ))>ε1) && ((fabs(b-a)/2)>ε2)) //The accuracy of the definition of the root
        {
            if ((f(a)*f(ξ))<0) 
            {
                b=ξ;
            }
            else 
            {
                a=ξ;
            }
            ξ=(a+b)/2;
            res(i+1, a, b, ξ, ε1, ε2); //Print results
            i++;
        }
        printf("Root ξ=%.7f found after %d iterations\n", ξ, i);
        printf("Function f(ξ)=%.10f found after %d iterations\n", f(ξ), i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wZvQ.jpg)

Comment: Re “I actually don't even see at which point the function is calculated 3 times”: In `(fabs(f(ξ))>ε1)`, `f(ξ)` calculates the function. In `(f(a)*f(ξ))<0`, `f(a)` and `f(ξ)` calculate the function. That is three times.

Comment: Note that identifier names such as `ξ` and `ε1` might not be supported.

Comment: @  Eric Postpischil, yes but how can I do calculations without these calculations. In `(fabs(f(ξ))>ε1)` I am checking the accuracy, in  `(f(a)*f(ξ))<0` I am also checking the conditions. This is how bisection method works. I have no idea how to combine this in one step and not even sure if it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only including relevant lines

Replace:

```
double Bisection(double a, double b, double ε1, double ε2)
{
    double ξ=(a+b)/2;

    if (f(ξ)==0) 

    else 
    {
        while ((fabs(f(ξ))>ε1) && ((fabs(b-a)/2)>ε2))
        {
            if ((f(a)*f(ξ))<0) 

            ξ=(a+b)/2;
        }
   }
```

with

```
double Bisection(double a, double b, double ε1, double ε2)
{
    double ξ=(a+b)/2; 

    double val = f(ξ); // Here is the magic

    if (val==0) 

    else 
    {
        while ((fabs(val)>ε1) && ((fabs(b-a)/2)>ε2))
        {
            if ((f(a) * val )<0) 

            ξ=(a+b)/2;
            val = f(ξ); // And here
       }
   }
```

It's not really some secret trick we're talking about. It's only about saving the return value in a variable and use that variable instead of a function call whenever possible. If the argument to the function changes, then you need to execute the function again. Here is a simple example that makes a string uppercase.

```
void uppercase(char *str) {
    // Bad, because it's not necessary to calculate the string
    // length every iteration.
    for(size_t i=0; i<strlen(str); i++)     
        str[i] = toupper(str[i]);
}

// Instead, do this

void uppercase(char *str) {
    size_t len = strlen(str);    // Precalculate and reuse in loop
    for(size_t i=0; i<len; i++)            
        str[i] = toupper(str[i]);
}
```

Comment: @ klutt, thank you for explanation! I didn't know this trick. I understand now. I just started to learn and this is my first code in C.

Comment: @Gelios No problem, but this is really a thing you should ask your teacher directly ;)

Comment: This still evaluates `f` twice in each iteration, in `f(a)` and `f(ξ)`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I did not aim for a complete solution. I was only aiming to show the technique of reusing a function call by saving it in a variable. Feel free to post an answer with a complete solution if you want.